# Normalizing the similarity score provided by gensim method most_similar_cosmul

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, semantics, similarity

I am trying to decide whether to use the gensim methods most_similar() and most_similar_cosmul() for a project where I am trying to find a set of words that are similar to a list of inputs.

While both methods provide an argument that restricts the number of words in the result set (default:10), I am trying to select words based on a similarity threshold (say 0.5). This works well between the two methods if there is a low number of positive words that contribute to the similarity.

However, while the regular most_similar()-method (linear) returns a relatively stable similarity score for each output-pair independent of the number of input words, the most_similar_cosmul()-method (multiplicative) returns increasingly small similarities.

I am wondering if there is any way to normalize the similarities provided by the most_similar_cosmul method so that they are independent of the number of input words. The most_similar_cosmul method is based on the paper “Linguistic Regularities in Sparse and Explicit Word Representations” by Levy and Yoav Goldberg.

```
>>> print(model.wv.most_similar(['digital_transformation','digital']))
[('social_mobile', 0.6574317216873169), ('social_networking', 0.653410792350769), ('mobile', 0.6508731245994568), ('mobile_social', 0.6483871340751648), ('digitization', 0.6388466358184814), ('digital_platform', 0.6366733908653259), ('digitalization', 0.6243988871574402), ('omni-channel', 0.6230252385139465), ('multi-channel', 0.6205648183822632), ('digital_marketing', 0.6161972284317017)]

>>> print(model.wv.most_similar_cosmul(['digital_transformation','digital']))
[('social_mobile', 0.6048797965049744), ('social_networking', 0.6038507223129272), ('mobile_social', 0.5969080328941345), ('digitization', 0.594704270362854), ('mobile', 0.5940128564834595), ('digital_platform', 0.5880148410797119), ('digitalization', 0.585797905921936), ('omni-channel', 0.5844268798828125), ('multi-channel', 0.5779333710670471), ('digital_marketing', 0.575140118598938)]



>>> print(model.wv.most_similar(['digital_transformation','digital','virtual']))
[('mobile', 0.6831567883491516), ('social_networking', 0.6692748665809631), ('social_mobile', 0.6688156127929688), ('cloud-based', 0.6612646579742432), ('cloud', 0.6573182344436646), ('mobile_social', 0.656197190284729), ('connected', 0.6240546107292175), ('physical_digital', 0.6219688653945923), ('digital_platform', 0.6217926740646362), ('digital_content', 0.6217813491821289)]

>>> print(model.wv.most_similar_cosmul(['digital_transformation','digital','virtual']))
[('mobile', 0.4431973695755005), ('social_networking', 0.4394254982471466), ('social_mobile', 0.43778157234191895), ('cloud', 0.4324479103088379), ('cloud-based', 0.43241411447525024), ('mobile_social', 0.4277876913547516), ('connected', 0.4095992147922516), ('physical_digital', 0.40511685609817505), ('digital_content', 0.40396806597709656), ('digital_platform', 0.40359607338905334)]



>>> print(model.wv.most_similar(['digital_transformation','digital','virtual', 'online']))
[('mobile', 0.7285350561141968), ('online_mobile', 0.6857519745826721), ('social_networking', 0.6757094264030457), ('mobile_social', 0.6697002053260803), ('digital_platform', 0.6669844388961792), ('social_mobile', 0.6654024720191956), ('digital_content', 0.6573283076286316), ('physical_digital', 0.6509564518928528), ('multi-channel', 0.6482810974121094), ('cloud-based', 0.64772629737854)]

>>> print(model.wv.most_similar_cosmul(['digital_transformation','digital','virtual','online']))
[('mobile', 0.35193151235580444), ('social_networking', 0.3212329149246216), ('online_mobile', 0.31998541951179504), ('mobile_social', 0.31541353464126587), ('social_mobile', 0.3134937584400177), ('digital_platform', 0.31218039989471436), ('digital_content', 0.3066185712814331), ('physical_digital', 0.3035270869731903), ('cloud-based', 0.301998496055603), ('multi-channel', 0.30137890577316284)]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the `_cosmul` calculation's theoretical benefits generalize this way - to any number of `positive` words, with no `negative` words. (It's not used that way in that paper, IIRC, and the implementation in Gensim was only motivated by the simple 2-positive & 1-negative analogy-solving benefits. Does the value go down even if the multiple words are very close, or even the same word repeated?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I didnt realize that the method might not be generalizable in that way. I just checked the values if the words are the same. The value does indeed go down for each additional word in the positive word-list even if it is the same word. I'll guess I have my answer then, _cosmul is just not generalizable to my problem.